# What to do with old LEGO Magazines

Tags: shopping, value

I'm in the process of moving, and I have come upon my old collection of LEGO magazines. All from the early 2000s, I have the LEGO Magazine, the Mania Magazine, and a bunch of Shop-at-Home catalogues.

Are these of any value? I checked e-bay, and I saw a few lots of maybe 10 or so, but nothing seemed to be moving. I've sitting on close to 100 of these things. I need to get rid of them, but I'd hate to just toss them. (I may give them to a neighborhood kid, but his parents might get a bit overwhelmed with 100 LEGO magazines suddenly showing up on the doorstep!)

I'd appreciate any feedback from y'all. (I live in Boston if anyone else is nearby.)

Answer (score 5):

You might consider donating them to your local library, or an after-school program. Kids love to flip through them!

Answer (score 1):

They are listed on bricklink, they seem to be sold from time to time. I estimate for about 30 cent each on average...

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=462&catType=B&v=1